# Converter World/Excel Para PDF

Tags: c#

Alguém conhece alguma api open source para converter documentos world e excel para pdf? Estou usando atualmente interop do windows contudo ela só funciona se eu instalar o office no servidor. Eu preciso remover essa instalação. No meu sistema eu salvo a Extensão do arquivo que pode ser (doc, docx, xls, xlsx) e os bytes. E quando o usuário deseja visualizar o arquivo eu mostro documento na tela para ele. Isso tudo é um sistema web. Atualmente está funcionando, contudo usando interop windows, preciso achar uma outra alternativa open source que não depende de office instalado. Alguém conhece? tentei o openxml mais pelo eu vi ele não convert para pdf apenas manipula arquivos.

Comment: Não necessariamente precisa ser em c# a conversação, pode ser outra linguagem, neste caso faço uma interop entre as linguagem.

Comment: Espero que a minha resposta tenha sanado as suas dúvidas, qualquer coisa estou a disposição.

Comment: Api free ainda não existe, tem api pago que faz exatamente o que você quer fazer: https://www.convertapi.com/docx-to-pdf

Answer (score 3):

Existem vários *Frameworks* para essa solução, o que mais utilizei foi o [EEPLus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) (que é apenas uma *DLL* e não precisa ser instalado), mas existem muitos outros como:

- [CloseXml](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml)
- [Open XML SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) ([veja artigo](http://www.devmedia.com.br/excel-e-open-xml-sdk-gerando-novas-planilhas-xlsx-a-partir-de-templates/25854))
- [NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi)

Como disse o que mais usei e tive uma melhor experiencia foi o *EEPLus*.

Veja como é fácil utiliza-lo :

**Criar Aba**

```
private static ExcelWorksheet CreateSheet(ExcelPackage p, string sheetName)
{
    p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);
    ExcelWorksheet ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
    ws.Name = sheetName; //Setting Sheet's name
    ws.Cells.Style.Font.Size = 11; //Default font size for whole sheet
    ws.Cells.Style.Font.Name = "Calibri"; //Default Font name for whole sheet

    return ws;
}
```

**Juntar colunas**

```
//Merging cells and create a center heading for out table
ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Sample DataTable Export"; // Heading Name
ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, dt.Columns.Count].Merge = true; //Merge columns start and end range
ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, dt.Columns.Count].Style.Font.Bold = true; //Font should be bold
ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, dt.Columns.Count].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center; // Aligmnet is center
```

**Adicionar stilo na celula**

```
//Setting the background color of header cells to Gray
var fill = cell.Style.Fill;
fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Gray);
```

**Adicionar estilo de borda**

```
//Setting Top/left,right/bottom borders.
var border = cell.Style.Border;
border.Bottom.Style = border.Top.Style = border.Left.Style = border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
```

**Adicionar formula**

```
//Setting Sum Formula
cell.Formula = "Sum(" + ws.Cells[3, colIndex].Address + ":" + ws.Cells[rowIndex - 1, colIndex].Address + ")";
```

**Adicionar imagem**

```
private static void AddImage(ExcelWorksheet ws, int columnIndex, int rowIndex, string filePath)
{
    //How to Add a Image using EP Plus
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(filePath);
    ExcelPicture picture = null;
    if (image != null)
    {
        picture = ws.Drawings.AddPicture("pic" + rowIndex.ToString() + columnIndex.ToString(), image);
        picture.From.Column = columnIndex;
        picture.From.Row = rowIndex;
        picture.From.ColumnOff = Pixel2MTU(2); //Two pixel space for better alignment
        picture.From.RowOff = Pixel2MTU(2);//Two pixel space for better alignment
        picture.SetSize(100, 100);
    }
}
```

**Converter para PDF**

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();  
//Load excel file  
workbook.LoadFromFile(info.Name);  
//Save excel file to pdf file.  
workbook.SaveToFile("result.pdf", Spire.Xls.FileFormat.PDF);
```

**Links de tutoriais :**

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/48c038/create-excel-and-convert-it-to-pdf-by-free-api/

http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.com.br/2011/06/creating-reports-in-excel-2007-using.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/680421/Create-Read-Edit-Advance-Excel-Report-in

http://www.jimmycollins.org/blog/?p=547

Comment: Sua resposta não tem nada a ver com a pergunta do cara, ele quer somente converter **word** para **pdf** e não gerar arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente usar o EPPlus e o Spire.Xls. Não utilizei, mas pelo que pesquisei não é preciso instalar o Office no servidor.

Comment: Spire.xls funciona o problema que ele coloca uma mensagem informando que foi gerado por essa ferramenta.

Comment: o EPPlus é possível converter para PDF?

Comment: Sim, é possível veja a minha resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizo a biblioteca [EEPLus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus).
A biblioteca *EPPlus* também pode ser baixada pelo *NuGet*.

Segue exemplo de um código que gera um arquivo *Excel* a partir de um *DataTable*:

```
Private Sub CreateAndFormatExcel(ByVal dt As Data.DataTable)
    Dim fileName As String = "exemplo.xlsx"

    Using pck As New OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage()
        'Excel Properties
        pck.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Nome do Autor"
        pck.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Titulo do Excel"
        pck.Workbook.Properties.Company = "Nome da Empresa"
        pck.Workbook.Properties.Subject = "Subject"
        pck.Workbook.Properties.Comments = "Comentarios"
        pck.Workbook.Properties.Manager = "Manager"
        pck.Workbook.Properties.HyperlinkBase = New Uri("http://google.com")

        'Create the worksheet
        Dim ws As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(Resources.Standard.ListaFaltas)

        'Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
        ws.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dt, True)

        Dim rangeCell As String = "A1:F1"

        Using rng As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRange = ws.Cells(rangeCell)
            rng.Style.Font.Bold = True
            rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid
            'Set Pattern for the background to Solid
            rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Drawing.Color.Red)
            'Set color to dark blue
            rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Drawing.Color.White)
        End Using

        ws.Cells(rangeCell).AutoFilter = True

        'Congela painel
        ws.View.FreezePanes(2, 2)

        'Write it back to the client
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" & fileName & "")
        Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray())
        Response.End()
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: preciso converter para pdf e não gerar arquivo, sabe se é possível?

Comment: sabe me dizer ?